# AWS Beanstalk app version history

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple environments for one application in Elastic Beanstalk. Under "Application versions" we can see on which environment which version is deployed.

Is there a way to see all the history of deployment for specific environment?

Comment: Can you not see all previously deployed versions and their destination environments in the Application Versions tab?

Comment: I can see all versions, but I can not see where they were deployed. So I see only the current environments using that version.